# C#: Calling web service through service reference: Content-Type Header missing

Tags: c#, soap, visual-studio-2015, wsdl

I'm trying to access http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl through C#.

I have added it as a Service Reference. Now i have the following code:

```
public static string checkVat(string _countryCode, string _vatNumber, string _companyName, bool _isValid, string _companyAdress)
    {
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl");
        var client = new ServiceReferenceCheckVat.checkVatPortTypeClient(binding, endpointAddress);

        string response = client.checkVat(ref _countryCode, ref _vatNumber, out _isValid, out _companyName, out _companyAdress);

        return response;
    }
```

This line:

```
string response = client.checkVat(ref _countryCode, ref _vatNumber, out _isValid, out _companyName, out _companyAdress);
```

is now **throwing following exception**:

An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An HTTP Content-Type header is required for SOAP messaging and none was found.

Edit: I call this class from X++, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work. The problem was a wrong endpoint adress.

Instead of using http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl (from which the referenced service was created from),  you have to use http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService

This link is also automatically used in the app.config file. **It works but for some reason it looks kinda wrong. If someone can explain it more, that would be great.**

Comment: I did the same mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add setting to your web config. It has to be add automaticly when you add this web service. I tried and It retuned data to me.

```
  <setting name="WebApplication6_eu_europa_ec_checkVatService" serializeAs="String">
    <value>http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService</value>
  </setting>
```

and this may help you [this](http://vatid.eu/)

can you try this?

```
    public static string checkVat(string _countryCode, string _vatNumber, string _companyName, bool _isValid, string _companyAdress)
    {
        var client = new eu.europa.ec.checkVatService();
        return client.checkVat(ref _countryCode, ref _vatNumber, out _isValid, out _companyName, out _companyAdress).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: i have an add.config. If i add it there, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Can you try this?
 public static string checkVat(string _countryCode, string _vatNumber, string _companyName, bool _isValid, string _companyAdress)
        {
            var client = new eu.europa.ec.checkVatService();
            return client.checkVat(ref _countryCode, ref _vatNumber, out _isValid, out _companyName, out _companyAdress).ToString();
        }

Comment: Gives me the same exception at the same line.

Comment: how did you add this webservice to your project?

Comment: Right click > add service reference and pasted in the URL. As a reference i used this: https://ax.help.dynamics.com/en/wiki/dynamics-ax-7-services-technical-concepts-guide/#consuming-external-web-services but it is written the same way everywhere else.

Comment: Try this, 1- Right click to References, 2- click Add Service Reference, 3- click Advanced (bottom left), 4- click Add Web Service, 5- Enter url and go, 6- Click Add Reference